# How to Delete Fold that Not Connected

Tags: linux

Under Centos server (no Desktop), I have `mkdir`ed a fold under `/mnt/`, after some operation (I don't know what I have done with it -_-), the `ls` output like this:

```
total 0
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? mybucket
```

I tried to `stat` it:

```
stat: cannot stat ‘mybucket’: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

then I tried `rm -rf mybucket`, the `rm` saied:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘mybucket’: Is a directory
```

How to remove that file in command line environment?

---

**Update**:
I now remember the operations: The fold is mounted as a FUSE (user space file system), and the host file system not recognise it. Just `init 6` will stop the FUSE and the `rm` operation works well.

Answer (score 6):

The fold is busy(now mounted as a FUSE), you can not `rm` or `stat` it, just `umount` it, and this will recover the fold from FUSE to local file system, then you can do anything you want on the fold.

Comment: Just want to add here, the folder I was trying to remove, was being used by GlusterFS. I removed the GlusterFS volume but did not unmount the file system that might have caused it to end up in undetermined state. After I unmounted it, I was able to remove.